# UIImagePickerController blocking Segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller, segue

I have a `UITabBarController` with **"5 tabs"**. The center tab is a `UIViewController` (embedded in a `NavigationController`) that contains a `MapView` with several other views layered on top of it including a `UITextView` and two `UIButtons`. One of those buttons opens a `UIImagePickerController`, the other triggers an **API** call using **"AFHTTPRequestOperationManager"** and then manually fires `[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"SomeDetailView" sender: (id)self];` from the **view controller** (it's a push segue that renders a detail view).

The issue that I'm having is that if the camera button is tapped, and the `UIImagePickerController` is instantiated, it ultimately blocks the segue transition later on. It doesn't matter if I choose a photo from the gallery, take a new photo, or take no photo at all and cancel the picker. Any of those scenarios will block the segue transition.

The actual segue event is still fired, and the `prepareForSegue` method is still executed but the actual transition does not happen. However, if I tap on another tab on the `UITabBarController`, and then tap back to the center tab, the segue transition does happen and I get the "Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions" warning.

Things I've ruled out:

- I'm using SVProgressHUD to show status while API calls are being made. I've removed it; didn't help.
- Everything related to AFNetworking has been removed. Simply tapping a button to fire `[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"SomeDetailView" sender: (id)self];` with no API calls, after the picker has been shown, causes the same problem.
- Using blocks or GCD to try and delay that segue transition has not helped
- Turning off animation when presenting or dismissing the image picker did not help

Other info:

- `View controller-based status bar appearance` is set to NO
- The center UIViewController hides the NavigationBar. The detail view that it segue's to shows the NavigationBar. If the user dismisses the detail view controller, the NavigationBar is hidden again
- calling `[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO]` or not makes no difference.
- Here's the delegate methods the center view controller implements: `MKMapViewDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate, UITextViewDelegate`
- This odd behavior seems to have just started with iOS 7.1 - This version of the app has been in production and working fine for around 6 months.

Any ideas what could be causing the image picker to block **subsequent segues**?

Answer (score 0):

One line of code... Famous last words.

The problem was that I subclassed the UITabBarController and implemented the `viewWillAppear` method but did not call `[super viewWillAppear:animated];` - Once I added that everything worked again.